# How to enroll a student to a classroom using Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I'm trying to write a script (with google apps script) that reads a spreadsheet in which there is a list of students to enroll in my classrooms: they are about 2,000.
The target is to create a profile of the student with the correct name/family name and email address, in addition should be nice to send an email to the student enrolled.
I explored classroom.invitation (I red it somewhere in stack exchange questions): it sends email to the student, but it doesn't permit to set the name/family name of the student.
Any suggestion?

Comment: What do you mean by `set the name/family name of the student`?

Comment: We open our classrooms to all the external domains, so we have students enrolled with gmail.com, yahoo.com, hotmail.com, etc. emails. In many cases the people doesn't specify clearly his name and family name in the email creation, so its quite hard for us (in some cases) to associate the email to the student. I was looking for a way to set the correct name and family name from the script: actually it should be possible by accessing the profile, but it isn't accessible while the student doesn't accept the inivitation.